# how to filter on TV parameter?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

tell me how properly in **Modx Revolution** correctly filter by **TV settings**? I need depending on the id of the user to **show/hide content**. Display the content by using the getresources:

```
[[!the getresources?
&showHidden=`1`
&tpl=`order`
&limit=`10`
&includeContent=`1`
&includeTVs=`1`
&resources=`6,7,8,9`
&debug=`1`
&tvPrefix=`
&tvFilters=`{"tv.user_id":[[!+modx.user.id]]}`
&processTVs=`1`]]
```

does not work at the moment nothing( Tell me what is the problem? Whether in the syntax or logic

thanks in advance

Comment: and you have mistake in `&tvPrefix=\`` - missing second `\``

Comment: i assume also that `the getresources` is just a fast typo, it should be `getResources`

Answer (score 1):

In http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources snippet:

```
&tvFilters=`user_id==[[!+modx.user.id]]`
```